# How to view a privilege level attached to a command in Junos?

Tags: juniper-junos

According to Juniper documentation, [each top-level CLI command and each configuration statement has an access privilege level associated with it.](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/junos-os-login-class.html) Is there a command which allows one to see the privilege level attached to a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want would be `show cli authorization`.  You won't be able to get down to the individual command level unless you specify them yourself with things like `allow-commands`, `deny-configuration`, etc.

It will show the user logged in, what permissions they have.

Here's an example of a custom login class that has all permissions except for specific types of configuration modes:

```
jhead@SRX1> show cli authorization
Current user: 'jhead       ' class 'CUSTOM'
Permissions:
    access      -- Can view access configuration
    access-control-- Can modify access configuration
    admin       -- Can view user accounts
    admin-control-- Can modify user accounts
    clear       -- Can clear learned network info
    configure   -- Can enter configuration mode
    control     -- Can modify any config
    edit        -- Can edit full files
    field       -- Can use field debug commands
    firewall    -- Can view firewall configuration
    firewall-control-- Can modify firewall configuration
    floppy      -- Can read and write the floppy
    interface   -- Can view interface configuration
    interface-control-- Can modify interface configuration
    maintenance -- Can become the super-user
    network     -- Can access the network
    reset       -- Can reset/restart interfaces and daemons
    rollback    -- Can rollback to previous configurations
    routing     -- Can view routing configuration
    routing-control-- Can modify routing configuration
    secret      -- Can view secret statements
    secret-control-- Can modify secret statements
    security    -- Can view security configuration
    security-control-- Can modify security configuration
    shell       -- Can start a local shell
    snmp        -- Can view SNMP configuration
    snmp-control-- Can modify SNMP configuration
    storage     -- Can view fibre channel storage protocol configuration
    storage-control-- Can modify fibre channel storage protocol configuration
    system      -- Can view system configuration
    system-control-- Can modify system configuration
    trace       -- Can view trace file settings
    trace-control-- Can modify trace file settings
    view        -- Can view current values and statistics
    view-configuration-- Can view all configuration (not including secrets)
    all-control -- Can modify any configuration
    flow-tap    -- Can view flow-tap configuration
    flow-tap-control-- Can modify flow-tap configuration
    flow-tap-operation-- Can tap flows
    idp-profiler-operation-- Can Profiler data
    pgcp-session-mirroring-- Can view pgcp session mirroring configuration
    pgcp-session-mirroring-control-- Can modify pgcp session mirroring configuration
    unified-edge-- Can view unified edge configuration
    unified-edge-control-- Can modify unified edge configuration
Individual command authorization:
    Allow regular expression: (^configure exclusive$)|(^edit exclusive$)
    Deny regular expression: (^configure.*)|(^edit.*)
    Allow configuration regular expression: none
    Deny configuration regular expression: none
```

Here is an even more restricted example where individual categories are configured instead of `all`:

```
jhead@SRX1> show cli authorization
Current user: 'jhead       ' class 'CUSTOM'
Permissions:
    admin       -- Can view user accounts
    routing     -- Can view routing configuration
    routing-control-- Can modify routing configuration
    system      -- Can view system configuration
    view        -- Can view current values and statistics
Individual command authorization:
    Allow regular expression: (^configure exclusive$)|(^edit exclusive$)
    Deny regular expression: (^configure.*)|(^edit.*)
    Allow configuration regular expression: none
    Deny configuration regular expression: none
```

Comment: I tried this in a lab environment and most of the permissions simply permit to view or modify certain part of the configuration. As much as I tested, then only following permissions are directly related to some operational mode command group: `field`, `view`(`show` commands), `reset`(`restart <SERVICE_NAME>` commands), `network`(`ping`, `telnet`, `ssh` etc), `shell`(`start shell <SHELL>` command) and `clear`(`clear` commands).

Answer (score 0):

It's in the table you've linked to: *read-only* can only view, *operator* can additionally run `clear`, `network`, `reset`, `trace`, and `view` and *superuser* can do everything.

If you create your own class the permission bit table below shows all the privileges you can assign to it.

Comment: I meant the association between the commands and permission bits. For example, which permissions requires a `file copy /var/tmp/file.txt re1:/var/tmp/` command? Or `monitor interface em0` command. I guess one way to solve this would be an additional `display` option, e.g `monitor interface em0 | display required-permission`